# How can I get python to output just string out of a list?

Tags: python

```
import random as r

list = ['left','right','center']

shoot = r.choices(list)
print('python says, shoot ' + str(shoot))
```

How can I get it to output just `left` or `right` or `center` instead of `['left']`

Comment: `random.choice()` w/o `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `random.choices` make multiples choice, use `random.choice`

```
import random as r

values = ['left','right','center']

shoot = r.choice(values)
print('python says, shoot', shoot)
```

---

Note

- don't use `list` as variable name, that's python list constructor
- `shoot` is already a string, no need of `str()`